# how to use db.execute in flask sqlalchemy inside blueprint without any models

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use flask_sqlalchemy inside my blueprints without writing any models. I am not sure if this is supported but my goal is to replace an existing db driver that I have written with sqlalchemy.
Here is how my app is structured right now

`my db.py file`

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

`my main.py file`

```
from .db import db

if os.getenv('FLASK_ENV') != 'production':
    load_dotenv(verbose=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
database_uri = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}??sslmode={sslmode}'.format(
            user=os.getenv('PGUSER'),
            password=os.getenv("PGPASSWORD"), 
            host=os.getenv("PGHOST"), 
            port=os.getenv("PGPORT"), 
            database=os.getenv("PGDATABASE"), 
            sslmode=os.getenv("PG_SSL")
        )
app.config.update(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=database_uri,
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False,
)
db.init_app(app)
app.register_blueprint(api, urlprefix="/")
cors = CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
app.secret_key = '079bc80c-cbd6-4fc5-b1aa-8fe01fde50dc'
```

I am then trying to use it inside my module in the following manner

```
from flask import current_app as app

rows = db.engine.execute("select users.username, users.id, string_agg(coalesce(keys.service, ''), ',') from users left join keys on keys.user_id = users.id where users.username = '" + username + "' and users.password='" + password + "'" + "group by (users.username,users.id)")
```

but I get the following error in my code while executing the code

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().
```

I have also tried changing my main.py code to the following

```
app = Flask(__name__)
database_uri = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}??sslmode={sslmode}'.format(
            user=os.getenv('PGUSER'),
            password=os.getenv("PGPASSWORD"), 
            host=os.getenv("PGHOST"), 
            port=os.getenv("PGPORT"), 
            database=os.getenv("PGDATABASE"), 
            sslmode=os.getenv("PG_SSL")
        )
app.config.update(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=database_uri,
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False,
)
with app.app_context():
    db.init_app(app)

    from flask.blueprints import Blueprint
    from app.api.routes import api 
    # from werkzeug.middleware.profiler import ProfilerMiddleware
    # app.wsgi_app = ProfilerMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, restrictions=[5], profile_dir='./profile')
    app.register_blueprint(api, urlprefix="/")

    cors = CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
    app.secret_key = '079bc80c-cbd6-4fc5-b1aa-8fe01fde50dc'
```

But I received the following error upon doing it

```
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'db'
```

What would be the right approach to get the code executing in the manner I wanted ?

Answer (score -1):

I just used your code and modified it a bit to create a working solution here: https://github.com/amucunguzi/SO-raw-sql-flask-sqlalchemy.

This `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context` is typical when you're trying to do something that requires `flask.current_app` but there is no "current (HTTP) request" i.e. the whole program execution was not initiated from `view` functions (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.current_app).

That being said, make sure you're importing your module correctly (see the `views.py` file). Also, it might be better to pass `db` as a constructor dependency to your module/service.